# Redirecting to a external url when magento order status changed

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, url, order-status

I created an observer which redirect to external url(like company's page)with new order status show.
I want to redirect my customer to an page where it will show that there order status changed.

```
  **<?php Class Atwix_Orderhool_Model_Observer extends
    Mage_Sales_Model_Order{

    public function implementOrderStatus(Varien_Event_Observer
    $observer) {
        /* @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getOrder();    // $stateProcessing = $order->getS;
        // Only trigger when an order enters processing state.
        if ($order->getOrigData('state')!=$order->getState()) {
            header("Location: 127.0.0.1:3122/magento19/creat_order.php");
        }
         } }**
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()
->setRedirect('[ your url ]')
->sendResponse();
```

for redirect anywhere in your webshop.